# How can I exclude email addresses from a data extension that are not part of a different data extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (using SQL)?

Tags: sql

I have a data extension (DE) with email addresses. (A data extension is basically a database table). However I want to take out the email addresses that also show up on a different DE (and the resulting email addresses + other data will have to be stored in a third DE), so basically exclude/suppress them.

I know I can use suppression lists [1] when sending an email, but I need to know how many recipients I will have before I'm actually clicking the send button... I'm looking for a SQL solution.

[1] = https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_suppression_lists_in_your_send.htm&type=5

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Is '[1] = url' where you want to place the sql script in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

So let's say your table with email addresses is called `SourceDE` and the table which has the email addresses to be excluded is called `ExcludeDE` with a field `email`, then you can do something like:

```
/* get the fields */
SELECT
  SourceDE.email,
  SourceDE.firstName
FROM SourceDE

/* join the two tables, but then only keep the rows 
where there is no matching email address from the ExcludeDE */
LEFT JOIN ExcludeDE
  SourceDE.email on ExcludeDE.email
WHERE
  ExcludeDE.email = NULL
```